# Unable to rank item based on sales,

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me to spot the error in the below code, I ma getting rownum as 1 for all the item. Ideally all the item should get different rownum based on Revenue

```sql
SELECT
  ITEM_NUM,
  LW_REV,
  ROW_NUMBER() over (
    PARTITION BY ITEM_NUM
    ORDER BY
      LW_OPS DESC
  ) ROWNUM
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ITEM_NUM,
      SUM(REVENUE) AS LW_REVENUE
    FROM
      D_DAILY_SALES
    WHERE
      ACTIVITY_DAY BETWEEN TO_DATE('20190302', 'YYYYMMDD') -6
      AND TO_DATE('20190302', 'YYYYMMDD')
      AND ITEM_NUM IN (
        '1002',
        '1120',
        '1144',
        '1145',
        '1204',
        '1240',
        '1245',
        '1344',
        '1345',
        '1365',
        '1387',
        '1500',
        '1512',
        '1573',
        '1577',
        '1597',
        '1672',
        '1706',
        '1746',
        '1748',
        '1788',
        '1854',
        '1895',
        '1928'
      )
    GROUP BY
      ITEM_NUM
    ORDER BY
      LW_REV DESC
  )
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: i very much doubt that the topicstarter is using MySQL database, i've changed the tags once and rollback the change because i was thinking a new MySQL 8 version update might have support for it.. MySQL documentation does not seams to have a `TO_DATE` in MySQL 5 or 8 @TheImpaler, the closest that matches is the `STR_TO_DATE()` function in MySQL.. i think the topicstarter is using Oracle database instead of MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are partitioning by item_num so every item starts at 1. Take out the Partition by - you just need the order by.

```
ROW_NUMBER() over (

    ORDER BY
      LW_OPS DESC
  )
```

NB. Shouldn't the order by be LW_revenue?

Comment: Thank you, Yes,  the order by will be LW_revenue. I am getting expected result now.